# How to find angle of rotation for Oriented Bounding Box?

Tags: 3d, trimesh

I have a Axis Aligned Bounding Box and a Oriented Bounding Box for a 3D Mesh.
How do I find the rotation matrix for Oriented Bounding Box?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about trimesh, but usually when you use any 3D tech, you should be able to get the rotation matrix of a bounding box directly from the exposed members of the class.

If not, any information like forward and up vector or euler angles are enough data to construct your rotation matrix out of it.